# How to get char from string by index in c language?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[11];
    int num;
    scanf("%s %i", &str, &num);
    printf("You typed %s and %i\n", str, num);
    if (num == 0)
    {
        printf (str);
    }
    else
    {
        printf (str[num]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The input is a phone number and a digit. If the digit is not 0, then print `number[digit]`.

It the last second line, I tried both `str[num]` and `&str[num]`. The first case will cause `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. The second one will return a string but not a char.

```
6479378812 1                                                                                                                                                                       
You typed 6479378812 and 1                                                                                                                                                         
479378812
```

But what I want is the second digit, which is `4`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Save time.  Enable all warnings.   I'd expect useful warnings  about `printf (str[num]);`

Comment: be aware of the difference between `%i` and `%d` using scanf().  while `%i` is nice because you can think *i = integer*, you usually want `%d`.  %d will always be base 10, and %i will auto-negotiate for example `012` as octal to mean 10 or `0x123` as hex to mean 291 which can sometimes be problematic  Unless you plan on octal or hexadecimal values as input use `%d` with scanf or sscanf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the formatting string for your printfs. The first needs a string format "`%s`", the second a single character "`%c`". You can find all the details about the format used in the formatting string of `printf()` [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[11];
    int num;
    scanf("%s %i", &str, &num);
    printf("You typed %s and %i\n", str, num);
    if (num == 0)
    {
        printf ("%s", str);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("%c", str[num]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&` in `scanf("%s %i", &str,..` is technical UB.  better to use `scanf("%s %i", str,..`

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify what do you want to print with the *printf* function.

```
printf("%c", str[num]);
```

With *%c* you tell to the function that you want to print a character.
If you want to print a whole string, you shall use *%s*.

By the way, you shall always specify the formatting string, because it is unsafe if you do not specify it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string